# Evenly allocate resources over multiple desinations

Tags: bash, files, scripting

I'm not quite familiar enough with bash to figure this out properly, I'll try to be brief with what I'm trying to figure out!

I have many paths stored in a file, along with their size (in G), such as below:(sizegb,path)

```
1,/bin/path1
5,/bin/path2
25,/bin/path3
```

There would be hundreds of paths like this.

I'll have a second file with destination disks they're going to be moved to such as (GB representing space left): (sizeGB,DISK)

```
376,DISK1
555,DISK2
```

Since there are generally hundreds of areas, varying in size, what would be the best way to "evenly" sort them between the two disks? that is to say, if I have 600 GB to move, to allocate ~400G to DISK2, and ~200G to DISK1 (so the remaining sizes would be 176GB,DISK1 and 155GB,DISK2)

with an output something like:

```
PATH,DISK
PATH,DISK2
```

Thanks in advance!

PS,

I'm also not asking for someone else to do this completely, I'm just looking for some good pointers on where to start, or ideas on what a practical way to do this would be!

Comment: Why do this manually? If you need to distribute data among multiple disks use e.g. ZFS or LVM. Both will handle this task automatically.

Comment: These paths are being moved across servers, everything is manages by a proprietary file-system manager.

Comment: Doesn't btrfs have this option?

Comment: This isn't the actual move of the data, it's setting up which paths should be moved to which destinations, the move itself is being handled by a separate script

Answer (score 0):

Load both files into arrays in your preferred language.  Iterate through the files and move it to the destination with the largest remaining free space.  When you do decrease the free space on that destination by the size of the file just moved there.

This method won't get you the absolutely most balanced arrangement but finding that solution cannot be computed in polynomial time (unless P=NP...which it doesn't, trust me ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out! is it possible to keep this within bash, or would I have to move to something like perl for the arrays?

Comment: It's possible to do in bash but bash arrays make my head hurt so I generally don't.  Almost any real language (ie. not a shell) will do it better than bash.